# Adding particle system after explode modifier causes blender crash

Tags: particles

I'm using Blender 2.74 and built the following scene:

1. Text_1 with explode modifier, dissolving in particle_system_1
2. Text_2 with build modifier and particle_system_2 with harmonic field interacting with particle_system_1
3. Object_1 with basic particle_system_3
4. Object_2 with basic particle_system_4

When playing animation (not rendering) Blender crashes. After removing particle_system_4, animation playback runs without crash. In Blender v2.63 it works fine also with particle_system_4.

I've found the following on the web according this issue:
https://developer.blender.org/T33112

How can I get the fixed version r51974 mentioned in the ticket?

Thank's a lot.

Comment: That was supposedly fixed in 2012. You need to post a new bug report and/or comment on the old report to say the issue is back.